# opencv none type error for region of interest

Tags: python, opencv

**Can somebody help me with solving this**
I am getting error in line roi

```
while(True):
    
    _ , frame = cap.read()
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (100, 100), (300, 300), (0, 0, 255), 3) 
    #region of intrest
    roi = frame[100:300, 100:300]
    img = cv2.resize(roi, (96, 96))
    cv2.imshow('roi', roi)
    

    img = img/255
```

**error:**

24     cv2.rectangle(frame, (100, 100), (300, 300), (0, 0, 255), 3)

25     #region of intrest

---> 26     roi = frame[100:300, 100:300]

27     img = cv2.resize(roi, (96, 96))

28     cv2.imshow('roi', roi)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

kindly help me in resolving this error

Comment: you have done no error checking in your use of the VideoCapture object. please look up in the documentation (tutorials, apidocs) how to do that. this question is asked every day on this site.

Comment: Always put guards to your code. first return value of cap.read() function is a boolean value representing if frame is retrieved successfully or not. Putting in a simple if condition would help you here.